# R Find and Replace within a string

Tags: r

I have a text file with a single column that I am trying to delimit but I can't workout the best way of doing it.

The column has different date formats followed by text, first I am trying to set all the dates into one format ddmmyyyy and then split the date. Example of 3 rows of data.

```
01/01/17 The address is...
17-05-2018 Please pay...
10 Jun 2018. Payee Name...
```

Expected

```
01/01/2017|The address is...
17/05/2018|Please pay...
10/06/2018|Payee Name...
```

I have a dataframe in R called `REPLACEVALUES` with 2 columns `OldText` and `NewText`. The csv file that I have loaded is called `Data`

I tried using `gsub` but I am getting an error, This  is the code I tried.

```
DataCleaned<-gsub(REPLACEVALUES$OldText, REPLACEVALUES$NewText, Data)
Warning message argument 'Pattern' has length >1 and only first element will be used
```

I have also tried using the below which doesnt work. `NewData<- Data 
NewData[]<-REPLACEVALUES$NewText[match(unlist(Data), REPLACEVALUES$OldText)]`

Comment: If the dates are always first, parsing them is doable: `as.Date(lubridate::parse_date_time(x, c('mdy', 'dmY', 'dmY')))` Separating the parts with regex is harder: `as.data.frame(do.call(rbind, strsplit(x, '(?<=\\d)\\.? (?=[A-Za-z\\s\\.]+$)', perl = TRUE)), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)` (where `x` is a character vector of the lines above)

Comment: The date is always first but some rows only contain text as it is missing the date. I have tried the above but I get all formats failed to parse `as.Date(lubridate::parse_date_time(Data, c('mdy', 'dmY', 'dmY'))) ` the regex gives a non-character argument error. Sorry I am a complete noob on this!

Answer (score 0):

This should get you started.  This is looking for 4 numbers (the year, basically), so it might not work with things stored in a format "mm/dd/yy".  You need to give it something to find to get the separation right.

```
library(tidyverse)
NewData <- Data %>%
  mutate(
    date = str_extract(OldText, ".*\\d{4}") %>% as.Date(tryFormats = c("%m-%d-%Y", "%d %b %Y", "%m/%d/%y"))) # check these, I believe %b is the month abbreviations
    rest = str_remove(OldText, ".*\\d{4}")
  )
```